# Windows 10 can't connect to Ubuntu 16.04 samba

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu-16.04, samba

I reinstall Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop 32bit on an old laptop and setup samba as https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/install-and-configure-samba#0 mentions. When I try to connect from a Windows 10 or Windows 7 machine I get the following:
Windows can't communicate with the device or resource(192.168.1.50)
The resource is available but is not responding to connection attempts.

any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem.

The problem is that Windows did not ask me for the samba user credentials and only generated an error 0x80070035.

So I did the following:

1. Go to "This PC"
2. Click on "Map network drive"
3. As Folder add "\\*samba server IP* \ *share name*"
4. **Check the "Connect using different credentials"**
5. Finish

Now windows should ask you the samba user credentials.

Comment: Lol, it actually helped me, thank you! Backslashes matters (after Unix life)

Answer (score 2):

I have this problem and able to fix this with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa without installing SMB v1 or change the regedit. There are few things need to be changed in /etc/samba/smb.conf

```
   passdb backend = tdbsam
   security = user
```

Change the networking

```
#### Networking ####

# The specific set of interfaces / networks to bind to
# This can be either the interface name or an IP address/netmask;
# interface names are normally preferred
interfaces = 192.168.100.63 wlp1s0

bind interfaces only = yes
```

And change user

```
#map to guest = bad user
force user = username
```

Don't forge to add your username into smb. The detailed step with images documented over here:
https://www.yodiw.com/install-samba-ubuntu-20-04-and-windows-10-sharing/

Comment: Binding the Interface worked for me which makes sense as I had more than one interface. I didn't have to change any users from what I had set up.

Answer (score 1):

In /etc/samba/smb.conf should add this

```
[global]
    client min protocol = SMB3
    client max protocol = SMB3
```

In windows 10 should edit this
enter in Local Group Policy Editor (search in windows) Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Network -> Lanman Workstation -> Enable Insecure Guest Logon - Enabled

Answer (score 1):

After a long battle with accessing samba share located on Debian VM from Windows 10, these steps saved my life:

> 1. Open the Local Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc).
> 2. In the console tree, select Computer Configuration/Administrative Templates/Network/Lanman Workstation.
> 3. For the setting, right-click Enable insecure guest logons and select Edit.
> 4. Select Enabled and select OK.

You can also take a look at the EventViewer to inspect the Microsoft-Windows-SMBClient/Security section. In my case there was an error "Rejected an insecure guest logon." before above steps was applied.

More info can be found here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/guest-access-in-smb2-is-disabled-by-default

Comment: wow, this is the working solution after so many attempts on any other solutions. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Samba (SMBv1 protocol) is no longer supported on Windows 10. To temporarily re-enable the SMBv1 protocol on Windows 10 follow these steps:

1. Open Control Panel.
2. Click on Programs.
3. Click on Turn Windows features on or off link.
4. Expand the SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support option.
5. Check the SMB 1.0/CIFS Client option.
6. Click the OK button.
7. Click the Restart now button.

I hope that helps. You should only use these steps as a temporary solution.

[image]

Reference: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-access-files-network-devices-using-smbv1-windows-10

Comment: Try this: Turning off Proxy Settings

1. Press Winkey + I to open Settings.
2. Go to Network and Internet.
3. On the left-hand side pane, click Proxy.
4. Turn off ‘Automatic proxy setup’ and then scroll down to turn off ‘Manual proxy setup’
5. Reconnect to your network.
6. Connect to your SMB shares.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just a suggestion: you can install SSH on your linux machine and access it via FileZilla if you want GUI. Access to Samba is disable on Windows because of security.