# SMB Ubuntu share with WIN 10 1903 - protocol 3_11

Tags: windows, ubuntu-18.04, smb

recently we have problems with our Ubuntu SMB shares connecting from WIN 10 1903. ON one PC (complete separate net and new PCs updated) we can see with `smbstatus -version` that it uses smb3_11 with encryption. That work fine from our WIN 10 1903 PC also. But on another system net with other PCs, it handles protocol SMB3_02 without encryption. And we can not connect the ubuntu share from our WIN 10 1903 PCs at all. Can anyone here explain how we can force to handle SMB3_11 ?
Thanks

EDIT: I have made a protocol for SMB connection, and here you can see the not working and a working protocol. Could this be of an unsupported NIC? [image: bad win]

[image: good WIN]

Comment: You can change the share properties to not use encryption, other option is to change the max dialect (in the server) to 3_02.
If the client does not support 3_11 then you cannot force it to work with 3_11.
Basically is should work with 3_02 because the server and the client are doing a negotiate phase and agree on the max(dialect) , in your case in 3_02 and it should work because 3_02 support encryption.

Comment: Thank you ! Moreover I realized that it could be that my NIC has problems. In a VMWare it works fine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58528469/windows-10-cant-connect-to-ubuntu-16-04-samba/62095294#62095294 see this